# Convert char to float in c

Tags: c, floating-point, char, type-conversion

I need to convert char to float. I know we can do this with the help of atof() function. But I dont want to create another variable to hold the float. I want the converted float to go in the same variable. Like this

```
operand = atof(operand)
```

Here operand is of type char. I also tried casting like this

```
(float)operand = atof(operand)
```

but no use.

Here is the entire code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    float operand = 0.0F ;
    char operator = '0' ;
    printf("\nFollowing operators are supported : + - * / S E\n") ;
    float acc = 0.0F ;
    while((operand = getchar()) !=0 && getchar()==' ' && (operator = getchar()) != 'E') {
            (float)operand = atof(operand) ;
            switch (operator) {
                    case '+' : printf("\nAdd %f to Accumulator.\tResult : %f\n", operand , operand + acc);
                               acc+= operand ;
                    break ;
                    case '-' : printf("\nSub %f from Accumulator.\tResult : %f\n", operand, acc - operand);
                               acc-= operand ;
                    break ;
                    case '*' : printf("\nMultiply Accumulator with %f.\t Result : %f\n", operand, operand * acc);
                               acc = acc * operand ;
                    break ;
                    case '/' : printf("\nDivide Accumulator by %f.\tResult : %f\n", operand, acc / operand);
                               acc = acc / operand ;
                    break ;
                    case 'S' : printf("\nSet Accumulator to %f\n",operand) ;
                               acc = operand ;
                    break ;
                    default : printf("\nInvalid syntax\n") ;
            }
    }
```

}

Any help is welcome.

Comment: The aroma of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in this post is almost to stong to ignore.

Comment: @WhozCraig . I have mentioned the problem as well here. I need to convert char to float but without creating a new variable. I want the converted value to go into same variable.

Comment: `atof` does not convert a char into a float. It interprets a string as a decimal representation of a floating point value.

Comment: `char` and `float` are different sizes in memory.  This the basis for the XY problem accusation.

Comment: "But I dont want to create another variable to hold the float." this is possible in dynamic languages, but not c. Use another variable. They don't cost anything.

Comment: @weston Variables always cost something.  It just comes down to whether that cost is significant for the system you are using.  EG Embedded vs Desktop systems.

Comment: @PeterM strictly speaking, a new local variable won't necessarily cost anything, because the compiler may optimize it out of existence. In such a case as the OP's code (which doesn't, anyway, look like it's intended to run on embedded systems), I think this is a very real consideration. Readability wins. Let the compiler optimize. Hand optimize later iff it's necessary.

Comment: @PeterM The XY problem is where you're trying to solve X, but you don't know how, and you think you need Y, but you don't know how to do that either... so you ask about Y. No, the different sizes in memory have nothing to do with the XY problem, here... The Y is `atof`.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Fundamentally the OP wanted to use some function that would cram a float into a char. His misunderstanding of atof doesn't change that.  If there was some C function that did convert a char into a float, then the OP's original stated problem (about trying avoid creating a second variable) would still exist.

Comment: Thats getting cruel now. (Ps I'm an EE guy).

Comment: @davmac Without knowing the OP's setup, we can only make assumptions as to the probably memory constraints.  What I was replying to was an absolute statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's not the same as "converting a char into a float", from various hints in your question I think what you really want is this:

```
operand = operand - '0';
```

This converts the (usually) ASCII value in `operand` into the value that it represents, from 0 - 9.

Typically, `getchar` returns the character code of the character typed. So, for example, the ASCII code for the digit '0' is 48 (and for '1' is 49 and so on). If the user types a '0' then `getchar` will return 48, which is the character code for the digit 0. Now, if you subtract '0' (which is 48) - then you get 0. This works for digits 0 through 9 (i.e. '1' - '0' = 1, '2' - '0' = 2 and so on).

Comment: I think you might be right but it wouldn't hurt to explain.

Comment: @iharob ok, I added a little more explanation.

Comment: But remember that `getchar()` returns an `int` so using the right type for that is necessary.

Comment: @iharob you've lost me there. It's ok to assign an `int` value to a `float` variable, right?

Comment: @davmac . operand = (float)(operand - '0') did the trick (I suppose). Although, I've now run into a new problem (not in anyway related to this), but the  temporary results suggest float conversion was achieved. Thank you.

Comment: @davmac yes it's ok, but the return value of `getchar()` is `int`, which is not clear from it's name, since it seems that it would be `char`.

Answer (score 4):

`atof` does not convert a `char` to `float`, it converts a string that represents a floating point number to a `double`.

To convert a  `char` to `float`, just assign it, there is an implicit conversion from `char` to `float`.

```
  signed char a = 4;
  float f = a;  // f now holds 4.f
```

Comment: But i dont want to create a new variable. Thats the point. I want to go it in the same variable in one  smooth  step.

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler then just cast it to `float`, i.e., `(float) a` is a float of value `4.f`

Comment: Can you please clarify it wrt the code given ? I have edited to add my program.

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler Why don't you want to create a new variable? Why is that bad?

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler assuming `char` holds a character between `'0'` and `'9'` (and not a numerical value) then `(float) (a  - '0')` will give you the floating point result.  But you have  to create a new floating point variable to hold this result as you cannot change the type of a variable after you declared it.